# Drupal Views Teaser/body Toggle

Tags: ajax, dynamic, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a view in Drupal 6 (views 2) and it outputs a page using the table format.  I have several fields showing in the table, one being the node:body.  I would like to have only the teaser shown but a + symbol or other clickable element to switch that to the node body.  I don't want to have to reload the view or switch over as sometimes the view will have 400 rows.

The possible solutions I have been considering would be to use Views Accordian, but that does not keep the functionaly of the table to sort by the other fields.

The other option is some form of javascript or ajax update of the view to swap between the two fields, or exclude one from the display and reveal the other.

The other option would be some css based javascipt to limit the height of the body with a link that can then expand it to full height.

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could continue to use the table format, but add a jQuery plugin like [Readmore](http://rockycode.com/blog/jquery-plugin-readmore/).

Comment: I did think that the solution would be something like this but the next question of course is how do you implement it in a view.  I can see how the divs could work in the view, I guess having both the teaser and the body and then do some rewriting of the outputs.  Can you give something a little more specific.

Comment: The script I linked to takes care of generating its own teaser. You could use one of the existing divs that Views generates when calling the script (see the examples on the Readmore page linked to above).